# Why is getline() not reading all content in text file?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, spaces

I am using `ifstream` alongside `getline` in order to read all input from a text file of integers. The input is structured as an adjacency matrix. Right now I am having trouble with reading the remaining numbers after the first space in each row.

** I have played around with the example input and confirmed that it is only printing the first number in each row (row[0...n], col[0]).

Example Input:

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

Example Output:

```
0
1
0
```

Here is the source code:

```cpp
    // Prompt user for input
    cout <<"\nEnter filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << "Enter a start vertex: ";
    cin >> startVertex;

    // Assume max size is 25 vertices
    pointer = new int[25];

    // Fill pointer with contents
    ifstream newFile(fileName);
    int x = 0;
    while(getline(newFile, fileName)){
        pointer[x] = stoi(fileName); //cast string to int
        x++;
    }
    newFile.close();

    cout << "Count = " << count << endl; //Test counter

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cout << pointer[i] << " " << endl; // Test pointer contents
    }
```

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow must include all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. You need to show the input and output in the question, as text, not images.

Comment: Variables are cheap.  Don't reuse fileName for something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::getline()` reads a whole line of input, for example it reads `"0 1 0"` (first row).

Then the (somewhat surprising) behaviour of `std::stoi` comes into play:

> Discards any whitespace characters (as identified by calling isspace()) until the first non-whitespace character is found, then takes **as many characters as possible to form a valid base-n** (where n=base) **integer number representation** and converts them to an integer value. The valid integer value consists of the following parts:

Which means, `stoi` only parses the first number `0` and returns it. Thus you only parse the first number of each row.

You need to read the file element-wise not line-wise:

```
ifstream newFile(fileName);
int val;
int x = 0;
while(newFile >> val){
    pointer[x] = val;
    x++;
}
newFile.close();
```

---

As an unrelated addition: Think about what happens, when the file contains more than 25 entries. Consider to use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the quick answer. Just confirmed that you are 100% correct. I've instead decided to store the initial input as an array of strings, then convert the individual string at each index to an int.

Comment: Just saw your additional code recommendation. Much cleaner the way you wrote it. Everything is working good now. Thanks again!

Comment: @newwwman If the answer solved your problem / answered your question, then you should *accept* the answer, not just post a "thank you" comment.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with parsing the file line-wise. Just don't use `std::stoi()` to parse the numbers from each line, you can use `std::istringstream` instead, eg: `while (getline(newFile, line)) { std::istringstream iss(line); while (iss >> pointer[x]) { ... ++x; } }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would work too, yes, but it's an unneccesary step. Except if the elements need to be stored per row or the row holds any semantic that needs to be conserved.

Comment: @churill well, the file is formatted as a matrix, so rows and columns make sense to preserve

Comment: @RemyLebeau Generally yes, but the original code does not store the data as matrix anyway. So i wouldn't assume this to be of importance here.